# receiving integer through intents from another activity on button click not working correctly android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I am trying to set an amount for a multiple selction of images from a custom gallery. i have two buttons where i can choose the amount of images to selected. For now i have two buttons label as 4 and 5. Once i click say button 4 an integer value 4 is sent to another activity.

**Problem 1** on the receiving activity i get both integer values 4 and 5 even if i have clicked on only one button.

**Problem 2** MAX_IMAGE_SELECTION_LENGTH always returns null. This variable must have have either value of 4 or 5. It is used in other methods to set the amount of images to be selected.

> intent used to send the integer value. Class: CountChooser.java

```
 View.OnClickListener c4ClickListner = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent().putExtra("count4", 4);
        CustomGalleryActivity customGalleryActivity = new CustomGalleryActivity();
        customGalleryActivity.setIntent(i);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};

View.OnClickListener c5ClickListner = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent().putExtra("count5", 5);
        CustomGalleryActivity customGalleryActivity = new CustomGalleryActivity();
        customGalleryActivity.setIntent(i);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

> receiving activity class: CustomGalleryActivity.java

```
int MAX_IMAGE_SELECTION_LENGTH;



    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int count_4 = intent.getIntExtra("count4", 0);
    int count_5 = intent.getIntExtra("count5", 0);
    if(intent.hasExtra("count4")){
        MAX_IMAGE_SELECTION_LENGTH = count_4;
    }else if(intent.hasExtra("count5")) {
        MAX_IMAGE_SELECTION_LENGTH = count_5;
    }
```

How can i solve this? I also tried different solution available on stackoverflow but could not get it done.

Comment: Why are you setting an intent to an `Activity` instance within another Activity?

Answer (score 0):

```
 View.OnClickListener c4ClickListner = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      finish();
    }
};
```

override on finish method and put it inside:

```
Intent i = new Intent(CountChooser.this,CustomGalleryActivity.class);
       i.putExtra("count4", 4);
       startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:
You set an OnClickListener on a global View? What View is that?
Use?:

```
Button button1 = (Button) findviewbyId(R.id......)
button1.OnClickListener
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a single key word for both like count and chekh its value whether its 4 or 5
Now make a condition that checks if count has 5 or 4 like
If(count==4){

}else{

}

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with code given below in respective Activities.

**CountChooser.java**

```
View.OnClickListener c4ClickListner = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomGalleryActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("count", 4);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
};

View.OnClickListener c5ClickListner = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomGalleryActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("count", 5);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

**CustomGalleryActivity.java**

```
int MAX_IMAGE_SELECTION_LENGTH;

Intent intent = getIntent();
int count = intent.getIntExtra("count", 0);
if(count != 0){
  if(count == 4){
      MAX_IMAGE_SELECTION_LENGTH = 4;
  }else if(count == 5) {
      MAX_IMAGE_SELECTION_LENGTH = 5;
  }
}
```

Please let me know if this is helpful for you.

Comment: yes it is helpful. Though i had to make some modifications in my MainActivity.